# Constructors and array of object in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an application in C++. In the application I have the default constructor and another constructor with 3 arguments.
The user is providing from the keyboard an integer that it will be used to create an array of objects using the non default constructor. 
Unfortunately I haven't been able to finish it till now, since I'm having issues with the creation of the array of objects that they will use the non default constructor.
Any suggestions or help?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Station{

public:
    Station();
    Station(int c, char *ad, float a[]);    
    ~Station(); 


    void setAddress(char * addr){

        char* a;
        a = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(addr+1)));
        strcpy(a,addr);
        this->address = a;
    }

    void setCode(int c){
        code=c; 
    }

    char getAddress(){
        return *address;
    }

    int  getCode(){
        return code;
    }


    float getTotalAmount(){
        float totalAmount=0;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            totalAmount+=amount[i];
        }
        return totalAmount;
    }

    void print(){

        cout<<"Code:"<<code<<endl;
        cout<<"Address:"<<address<<endl;
        cout<<"Total Amount:"<<getTotalAmount()<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }


private:
    int code;
    char *address;
    float amount[4];

};


Station::Station(){
    code= 1;
    setAddress("NO ADDRESS GIVEN");
    amount[0]= 0.0;
    amount[1]= 0.0;
    amount[2]= 0.0;
    amount[3]= 0.0;

}


Station::Station(int c, char *ad, float a[]){

    if( (c>=1&& c<=10 ) ){
        code=c;
        address=ad;

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            amount[i]=a[i]; 
        }   

    }else{

        code= 1;

        setAddress("NO ADDRESS GIVEN");
        amount[0]= 0.0;
        amount[1]= 0.0;
        amount[2]= 0.0;
        amount[3]= 0.0;
    }   
}   


Station::~Station(){

}

int main(){

    int size,code;
    char *addrr;
    addrr = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(addrr+1)));
    float mes[4];

    do{ 
        cout<<"size of array:";
        cin>>size;

    }while(size<=0 || size>=11);

    //  Station *stations= new Station[size];
    //  Station** stations = new Station*[size];
    Station stations[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

        cout<<"code:";
        cin>>code;

        cout<<"address:";
        cin>>addrr;

        double amo=0;

        for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
            cout<<"values"<<k+1<<":";
            cin>>mes[k]; 
        }
    }
    /*
    for(int q=0;q<size;q++){
        stations[q].print();
    }
    */

    return 0;
}
```

the values that I'll take from `cin` I want to assign them to the objects of the array!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: show me the creation of arrays, do you use new or malloc?

Comment: you can have a look in the code above! thank you

Comment: that code has lots of problems. like memory leaks and Undefined Behavior. as a first step that is likely to fix most of that, replace all use of `char*` with `std::string`.

Comment: im not allowed to use string!

Comment: Then you'll have to use `char*` strings correctly. Unfortunately that's harder than it looks and always trips up new programers for while. Take it slow and methodically. Think about what memory you are using *every* time you write to a string. Remember those `'\0'` terminations.

Answer (score 11):

You can either create the array default-initialized and then fill the array with the wanted object:

```
foo arr[10];
std::fill(arr, arr+10, foo(some, params));
```

Alternatively you could use `std::vector` and do just:

```
std::vector<foo> arr(10, foo(some, params));
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++0x, you can use `braced-init-list` in new expression, which means you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int i, int j){std::cout<<i<<" "<<j<<'\n';}
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int *n = new int[3]{1,2,3};
    A *a = new A[3]{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    delete[] a;
    delete[] n;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled under g++ 4.5.2, using `g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -pedantic`

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you can't use `std::string`, this is going to be much more difficult.  The line `addrr = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(addrr+1)));` is not doing what you think it is.  Instead of using `malloc` to allocate on the heap and since there is no `free` (which will lead to a memory leak), it will be much easier if we allocate on the stack with a predetermined buffer size: `char addrr[BUFFER_LENGTH]`.  With `BUFFER_LENGTH` defined before `Station`'s declaration as `const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 20;` or some other appropriate length.

To use the non-default constructor, adding `stations[i] = Station(c, addrr, mes);` at the end of the for loop will do the trick.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    cout<<"code:";
    cin>>code;

    cout<<"address:";
    cin>>addrr; // do not read in strings longer than 20 characters or increase BUFFER_LENGTH’s size

    double amo=0;

    for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
        cout<<"values"<<k+1<<":";
        cin>>mes[k];
    }

    stations[i] = Station(c, addrr, mes);
}
```

But, this is not going to work properly since the constructor is copying the `addrr` pointer, not the data.  I would recommend also changing the data member `char *address` to `char address[BUFFER_LENGTH]`.  Then, in the constructor you can replace the line `address=ad;` with `strcpy(address, ad);`.

Note: `setAddress` and `getAddress` will now need to be updated.

Another line that is troubling is `Station stations[size];`.  This is non-standard since `size` is not a known at compile time.  Either use `Station *stations= new Station[size];` and remember to `delete` or if you can use a `std::vector`, use `std::vector<Station> stations(size);`

If you do go the `std::vector` route, using `push_back` will work nicely:

```
std::vector<Station> stations;

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

    cout<<"code:";
    cin>>code;

    cout<<"address:";
    cin>>addrr;

    double amo=0;

    for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
        cout<<"values"<<k+1<<":";
        cin>>mes[k]; 
    }

    stations.push_back( Station(c, addrr, mes) );
}
```