# Calling constructor for an array of objects in another constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, object, struct, constructor

I am trying to hardcode a bunch of values in an array of objects, `FloatParameterFields` by calling the constructor of each object in the array. I am calling these constructors in another constructor, `ParametersServerABS()`.

The array of objects `FloatParameterFields` is a private member of the `ParametersServerABS` class:

```
private:

    FloatParameterFields _floatParameters[FloatParameter::NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS];
    bool _safeMode;
```

In another file, I defined the enum and struct:

```
enum FloatParameter {
    CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0 = 0,
    CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_1,
    CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_2,
    CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_3,
    CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_4,
    NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS
};

enum AccessModes {
    READ_ONLY = 0,
    SAFE_WRITE,
    WRITE,
    NUM_ACCESS_MODES
};

struct FloatParameterFields {

    public:

        FloatParameterFields() :
                upperBound(0),
                lowerBound(0),
                value(0),
                id(NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS),
                mode(NUM_ACCESS_MODES) {
        }

        FloatParameterFields(float upperBound, float lowerBound, float value, FloatParameter id,
                AccessModes mode) :
                upperBound(upperBound),
                lowerBound(lowerBound),
                value(value),
                id(id),
                mode(mode) {
        }

        float upperBound;
        float lowerBound;
        float value;
        FloatParameter id;
        AccessModes mode;

};
```

In my first attempt I did:

```
ParametersServerABS::ParametersServerABS() :
        _safeMode(true) {

    // Hardcoding the values to the struct
    _floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0](2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
            FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0, AccessModes::WRITE);
    _floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_1](2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
            FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_1, AccessModes::SAFE_WRITE);
    _floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_2](2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
            FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_2, AccessModes::WRITE);
    _floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_3](2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
            FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_3, AccessModes::WRITE);
    _floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_4](2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
            FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_4, AccessModes::READ_ONLY);

}
```

This gave the error:

```
no match for call to 'FloatParameterFields) (double, double, double, FloatParameter, AccessModes)'
```

Upon further [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305874/2158231) I tried:

```
    // Hardcoding the values to the struct
    _floatParameters[FloatParameter::NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS]= {FloatParameterFields(2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
                FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0, AccessModes::WRITE),
        FloatParameterFields(2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
                FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_1, AccessModes::SAFE_WRITE),
        FloatParameterFields(2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
                FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_2, AccessModes::WRITE),
        FloatParameterFields(2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
                FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_3, AccessModes::WRITE),
        FloatParameterFields(2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
                FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_4, AccessModes::READ_ONLY)}
```

And got the error:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'FloatParameterFields' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')
```

I am most confused by my first attempt, why is it wrong? It seems to make sense yet I get an error... I even properly included the header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before entering the opening `{` of your constructor, all of your members are already initialised. That includes the `_floatParameters` array and all of its elements. When you then do...

```
_floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0](2.0, 2.0, 1.0,
        FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0, AccessModes::WRITE);
```

...this is seen as attempting to call `_floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0]` as though it were a function-like object. It is not seen as an initialiser, since the objects have already been initialised.

Similarly, you later do:

```
_floatParameters[FloatParameter::NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS]= { ... };
```

which is attempting to use the initialisation syntax for an array after the array has already been initialised.

Instead, you could use the constructor's member initialisation list:

```
ParametersServerABS::ParametersServerABS()
  : _safeMode(true),
    _floatParameters{
      {2.0, 2.0, 1.0, FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0, AccessModes::WRITE},
      // and so on...
    }
{
}
```

Comment: Oh, were they initialized in the part where I initialized a private array of structs?

Comment: @JustinLiang They are initialised when the object is constructed, immediately before entering the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `_floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0](...)` as if you had an array of functions, and you're calling one of its items. Even though arrays of functions do exist in C++, it doesn't seem to be what you tried to achieve.

Simply, you cannot call constructor like that. Here's a correct example:

`_floatParameters[FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0] = FloatParameterFields(2.0, 2.0, 1.0, FloatParameter::CHIP_CLOCK_RATE_0, AccessModes::WRITE);`

Your another approach could have worked, but there's a bug.

`_floatParameters[FloatParameter::NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS]= { ... }`

You're assigning an initializer list (i.e. list of values) into the `FloatParameter::NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS`-th item of `_floatParameters`. To setup an array you'd assign to `_floatParameters` directly. That [will work](http://ideone.com/e099W1) with vector, but [won't work](http://ideone.com/Hf2kcX) with plain old arrays.

`_floatParameters = { ... }`